# tbody is not filling up the width of the table but the content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

HTML:

```
<body class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <p class="display-3">Password Vault</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 800px;">
            <div class="container border t-box col-5">
                <table class="table table-hover t-responsive" >
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cons
                            </td>
                            <td class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">View</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.t-transparent{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.half-opaque{
    opacity: 50%;
}

.nav-t{
    height: 70px;
}

.t-box{
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.t-responsive{
    display: block;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

tr{
    max-width: 778px;
}
```

I am using bootstrap 5, the issue is that in bootstrap's table class, there are lines under each row. But in this case the lines are dependent on the tbody, which wraps the content responsively. How do i fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting `disaply:block` to the `<table>` element?

```
.t-responsive{
    display: block; // remove this
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It is causing table to take full width of the viewport.
If you want `<table>` to take full width as of parent container then set `width:100%`, etc.

Comment: I had display:block to make my table scrollable, removing it would make my table not scrollable anymore.

Comment: Instead changing display of table, you can make it's parent scrollable.
.container {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}